# my sub domains vanish with time

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a server running bind9.

When the propagation is done and i ping **domain.tld** i get **xx.xx.xx.xx** (where xx.xx.xx.xx is the server IP), if i ping **test.domain.tld** i get **xx.xx.xx.xx**, at this point it's all good.

My probleme is, the sub domain **test.domain.tld** *vanish* in ~24hrs, **test.domain.tld** can't be resolved anymore (while **domain.tld** is still ok), but **if I refresh the serial and reload bin9 it work again for 24hrs**.

I am quite a noob at this and i really need your help :)

***Files i modified :***

named.conf.local

```
zone "domain.tld" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.domain.tld";
    allow-query { any; };
    allow-transfer {
            xx.xx.xx.xx;
    };
    notify yes;
};
```

db.domain.tld

```
$TTL 86400
;
$ORIGIN domain.tld.
@            IN    SOA    nsxxxxxx.ip-xx-xx-xx.eu. postmaster.domain.tld. (
             2014112504  ; serial
             28800       ; refresh
             3600        ; retry
             1209600     ; expire
             86400       ; negative cache
             )
;
@           IN     NS   nsxxxxxx.ip-xx-xx-xx.eu.
@           IN     NS   ns.xxxxxxx.com.
@           IN     A    xx.xx.xx.xx
test        IN     A    xx.xx.xx.xx
```

EDIT:

server ip: **37.187.121.154**

domain: **fleshzor.com**

sub-domain: **code.fleshzor.com**

reverse: **ns331415.ip-37-187-121.eu**

dns: **ns.kimsufi.com**

EDIT 2 :
I duplicated the zone in my web hoster interface and for now, it works. If it still works tomorrow i will tag the question as answered.

I still don't understand how it was working (only for a short period) without the duplication of the zone in my web hoster interface.

Comment: Please consider to publish the actual domains and IPs. DNS issues are so much more easy to diagnose if you can query the servers in question.

Comment: i've edited my question

Comment: I see that the NS servers are not under your domain, are they still yours (do you administer them)? 

Can you give an example of the `code.fleshzor.com` domain not resolving? Do you get a SRVFAIl from the servers?

Comment: I don't administer the NS servers, the first one is **ns331415.ip-37-187-121.eu** (a reverse) and the 2nd one is **ns.kimsufi.com**

Comment: Look like i solved the problem... I had to duplicate the zone records in my web hoster interface.. I still don't understand how it was working for a short period without that. (i will tag the question as resolved if it still work tomorrow)

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming that those servers are administered through that interface...